# unable to install subclipse with Eclipse neon3 64 bit on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: svn, subclipse, eclipse-neon

I am trying to install Subclipse plugin from Eclipse Marketplace on Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise version on Eclipse Neon 3, 64 bit version.

[image: Marketplace Image]

[image: Error received]

> Unable to read repository at https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/archive/release/1.12.x/content.xml.
>
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I also tried to install via Help → Install New Software and added the link: [`https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/`](https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/).
This failed too.

How do I install this plugin? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you connect to internet at all through Eclipse?

Open the internal webbrowser. In Eclipse: Window -> show view -> Other -> General: Internal web browser.
Look up any normal adress, is it working?
Can you connect to another update site? Try for example Eclipse Emma: http://update.eclemma.org/ Do you see anything there?

What are your proxy preferences? Go to Window -> preferences -> General: Network connections.

The active provider:

> Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections.
>   Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened
>   without the use of a proxy server. Selecting Manual causes settings
>   defined in Eclipse to be used. On some platforms there is also a
>   Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that
>   were discovered in the OS to be used.

If internet is working fine outside of Eclipse, try changing to Native. After that, try Direct.

I have encountered problems where an update site would not load, then I had to remove it and add it again. This forces Eclipse to reread the contents of the site even if it has a cached copy. So, if you still get no connection to the indigo update site, but everything else is working, try that. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the indigo site. Just remember to copy the adress so you can add it again.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install Update -> Available Software Sites => select the entry and click the "Reload" button to the right. This is sometimes also helpful when you have a local update site for testing custom plugins

Comment: It does not work. The screenshot submitted by you is the first window. When I click on the Confirm button is when I get the error message.

Comment: Updated my answer, check once :)

Answer (score 6):

Go to Help > Install New Software ... > Add 
Then Add this Link http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x 
Check all the boxes then click Finish

You are probably in a company network that they are using some security protocoles; Otherwise Downloading then Installing is permitted.
I hope it works for you

Comment: I had the issue of company security ..This link helped.

Comment: Worked for me too, I had no problem with connection in general, using HTTP instead of HTTPS solved installation problem...

Comment: I tried this too. Didn't work for STS4

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was not able to install due to "error SSL handshake" connecting to https://dl.bintray.com ... Although the root certificate is inside the truststore (cacerts) of the jvm I was using

For some reason, my version of eclipse (STS4) is not using this truststore, I edited the .ini config file of eclipse SpringToolSuite4.ini and explicitly put this:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP instead of HTTPS, If you don't want to update the JVM at least to 1.8

E.g.: http://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/

The url is still valid

Answer (score 0):

You provided the error for using the bintray update site URL. That is what I would recommend you use.  The error is that your JVM will not make an SSL handshake.  You might need to use a newer version of the JVM to run Eclipse.

The update site URL still used in the marketplace is the old http tigris site. There is no way you are getting that same error from that site since it does not use SSL.  So for the error you are getting on that site we would have to see it.

You can also download the zipped update site via your browser and install it locally but I would update the JVM regardless.

Comment: I was able to test your suggestion. But thanks just the same for your inputs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Help->Install New Software->Add* and then add this link:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x/

The version will update in the future. Update the latest version every time. Otherwise, you will face JavaHL exception.

Refer http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL.

Comment: Basically the same answer was given by @ElhoussineZennati on Mar 16 at 16:55, only the version is different. Imagine how difficult it would be to find the right answer, if a new one is added with each new version.

Comment: Still, we can use the old version and it will install perfectly but when we add the svn URL, we will get JavaHL exception. So it is better to install the updated version at the start.

Comment: I think, that providing those additional details already qualifies the post as an answer. But as it was written - it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Eclipse 4.28 (2023) adds:

> ### [CVE-2021-41033: Enforce https protocol](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.28/platform.php#force-https)

> To address [CVE-2021-41033](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-41033), all access to external update sites and their artifacts is forced to use https, even when http is specified. The following system properties can be used to affect this behavior:
>
> ```
> p2.httpRule
>  redirect
>    http:// → https://
>  allow
>    http:// → http://
>  block
>    http:// → fail
> p2.ftpRule
>  redirect
>    ftp:// → ftps://
>  allow
>    ftp:// → ftp://
>  block
>    ftp:// → fail
> ```
>
> Adding the line `-Dp2.httpRule=allow` as the last line of the `eclipse.ini` can be used to restore the previous behavior.
>
> This can be relevant inside a corporate environment where the firewall may introduce certificates into the network traffic that are not recognized by the cacerts of the Java runtime, i.e., this may be used to avoid "`PKIX path validation failed`" exceptions that can otherwise be fixed only by importing the firewall certificate into the Java runtime's cacerts.
>
> These rules can be specified as configuration-scoped preferences available via the `Authorities` tab of the `Install/Update → Trust` preferences:
>
> Protocol Rules Preferences
>
> The default preference value of each rule is determined by the corresponding system property.